# Select rows from R table based on two columns in another table

Tags: r

I have two tables; table1 and table2, where table1 is much bigger than table2, but table2 is not fully contained in table1. I also have two ID columns - ID1 and ID2 in each table. I want to obtain the rows in table1 and table 2 in which the two ID columns coincide. If a pairing of ID's is in one table and not the other then the row should not be returned.

I tried `t1[which(t1$ID1 == t2$ID1 & t1$ID2 == t2$ID2`

It said that the longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length. Any ideas?

Comment: This is an inner join I think - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr::semi_join()` (and borrowing @thesixmax’s example data):

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
  semi_join(table2, by = c("ID_1", "ID_2"))
#   ID_1 ID_2 val
# 1  0_2  1_2   2
# 2  0_4  1_4   4

table2 %>%
  semi_join(table1, by = c("ID_1", "ID_2"))
#   ID_1 ID_2 val
# 1  0_2  1_2   1
# 2  0_4  1_4   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple repex:

```
table1 <- data.frame(
  "ID_1" = c("0_1", "0_2", "0_3", "0_4", "0_5"),
  "ID_2" = c("1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4", "1_5"),
  val = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)

table2 <- data.frame(
  "ID_1" = c("0_2", "0_4", "0_6", "0_7", "0_8", "0_9", "0_10"),
  "ID_2" = c("1_2", "1_4", "1_6", "1_7", "1_8", "1_9", "1_10"),
  val = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)
```

A solution using base R:

```
ids1 <- which(interaction(table1[,c("ID_1", "ID_2")]) %in% 
               interaction(table2[,c("ID_1", "ID_2")]))
ids2 <- which(interaction(table2[,c("ID_1", "ID_2")]) %in%
                interaction(table1[,c("ID_1", "ID_2")]))
overlap1 <- table1[ids1,]
overlap2 <- table2[ids2,]
```

Comment: You can omit the `which()` and this would still work (just using logical indexing instead of positions).